# List EMPNAME, PHONE, EMAIL for temporary or part time staff getting salary between 30000-50000 - arranged according to CITY, FACULTY and EMPID

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I am working on a query

List `EMPNAME`, `PHONE`, `EMAIL` for temporary or part time staff getting salary between 30000-50000 - arranged according to `CITY`, `FACULTY` and `EMPID`.

I am a bit confused because i thought when you use an `order by` or `group by` the columns need to be listed in the select statement.

I'm not sure how this should look because I was doing

```
select empname, phone, email 
 from employee
where emptype = 'PT' 
  and salary between 30000 and 50000
order by city, faculty, empid
```

some feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Your query is correct. `ORDER BY` sorts the results, and you're using it correctly. `GROUP BY` isn't needed here - it's used when you're  aggregating values with something like `SUM` or `COUNT` or `MIN`, etc. This looks like a homework question (and I'm OK with that), so I'm assuming your course will cover `GROUP BY` soon enough. Until then, don't worry about it :)

Comment: Eeep...it is a homework question. Sorry. i was just confused by the columns listed and ordering...but i appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Not a problem at all :) I think homework questions are fine as long as they follow the StackOverflow guidelines (ask a specific question, show your work), and you did both.

Comment: +1. Nicely asked question, as @EdGibbs said, and for the same reasons. You stated the problem clearly, explained the question, and showed what you did to try and solve it yourself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a proper question but a request for "feedback" on a homework solution

Answer (score 0):

You can order by a value that is not one of the fields selected.   A Group By is not needed for this query.
The query below (which is essentially what you have posted) will work.  This assumes both temporary and part time workers are identified by 'PT'.

```
SELECT empname, phone, email 
from employee
where emptype = 'PT' 
and salary between 30000 and 50000
order by city, faculty, empid;
```

Do both part time and temporary workers have the same empTpype?

If not, you need something like this:

```
select empname, phone, email 
from employee
where (
      emptype = 'PT' 
      OR
      emptype = 'TEMP'
      ) 
and salary between 30000 and 50000
order by city, faculty, empid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select empname, phone, email from employee
where emptype = 'PT' OR emptype = 'TEMP'
and salary between 30000 and 50000
group by empid order by city, faculty
```